# Open VBA code of active form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database with a huge amount of forms (300+) and VBA code. The backend of this Access db is in MS SQL.

When I am on a control in a form (in formview), I want to "jump" directly to the VBA code of this form without closing or putting the form in design mode. I can do this with a shortcut key which I assign to a function.

This works well when the control is not in a subform. But when this is the case, the code runs into an error telling me that the module of form cannot be found.

This is the code i use:

```
Dim sFrmName As String

sFrmName = Screen.ActiveControl.Parent.Name
If Nz(sFrmName, "") = "" Then Exit Function

'Open forms module
DoCmd.OpenModule "Form_" & sFrmName
```

How can i change this code so that i dont have to put the form in design mode to go to the VBA code of this form, which will also work for subforms? I know I can do this manually in VBE, but I'd like to do it in VBA.

Comment: All forms in our Access database have modules in form, that i know sure. Function above works great when activecontrol is in mainform, but not when it is in subform. I do get the right name of (sub)form, but then docmd.openmodule gives me an error that module cannot be found. When i set the same subform as a mainform, just for test, the same code above does work without errors. We have many subforms in use and the function above could save us much time when developing or troubleshouting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one way to do it, this also works for subforms:

```
Dim sFrmName As String

sFrmName = Screen.ActiveControl.Parent.Name
If Nz(sFrmName, "") = "" Then Exit Function

'Open forms module
'DoCmd.OpenModule "Form_" & sFrmName
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("Form_" & sFrmName).CodeModule.CodePane.Show
```